# Baby seat-belt wasn't provided on takeoff - worth complaining?

Tags: air-travel, safety, compensation, air-france, child-safety-seats

On AirFrance flight form Paris to Montreal yesterday the AirFrance crew forgot
to provide the baby seat belt before takeoff.

Moreover, no cabin check was performed in our segment before takeoff so we didn't  get the chance to ask for one.

I was still working on my laptop when the plane began moving and the electronic call to the crew was answered only after take-off; 
The crew apologized and gave us the seat-belt immediately for the rest of the flight

This is a security failure that could have ended in a tragedy.

Anything I can/should do about it?
What can I hope to achieve?

Thanks.

Edit: (How) Can I leverage this for a news debate about infant safety in airplanes?

Comment: I mean, what do you *want*? Money? An apology? A free ticket? These things happen. I was once on an international flight where the crew in one part of the cabin didn't secure it at all for landing -- and we had a *hard* landing.

Comment: Those things are actually banned from the US by the FAA because it was determined that in an accident the parents body has a tendency to crush the child. The only safe way to fly with a baby is in a separate seat strapped into an aircraft-approved car seat.

Comment: @Roddy "These things happen" - and mistakes or carelessness will happen increasingly often if everyone just passively shrugs and there are no consequences the majority of times

Comment: @user568458 -- Yes, and? I'm not sure what your point is or why you pinged me about it. I was asking the OP to clarify what they wanted out of the airline (money, an apology, etc.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, thanks for answering.
I am trying to understand what I should do based on other people's experience - If I invest the time in filing an official complaint - what might be the consequences? - If all that happens is a flight attendant loses her job, it ain't worth my time. On the other hand, if it gets to the news and security regulations are revised/debated - I might save an infant's life. Compensation? Nice to have, but I don't believe in it.

Comment: @Michael Did you use the attendant call button? And did you have a chance to ask earlier, or were you too busy with your laptop?  At the end of the day they're your kids and the ultimate responsibility is yours, not the airline's.

Answer (score 5):

Not all countries require (or even allow) the use of infant lap belts in aircraft. Sometimes, the crew is required to provide one and instruct you about its use. Other times, they are available if you ask but are not provided by default. And sometimes there are no infant lap belts available at all.

Comment: How do you find out if France/Canada are among those countries?

Comment: It's not about a specific country - it's Airline safety rules. AirFrance has its safety rules regardless of the countries they serve. Same procedures wherever they fly.